# function not reevaluated on each call

Tags: php, function, echo, call

Ok so I have a function: newCSRF($formID); that generates a CSRF token which I call in a form. like this

```
if(){
    echo "<some html form>". newCSRF("login-form")."<rest of html>";
}
```

on the same index.php page there's another form

```
if(){
    echo "<some html form>". newCSRF("register-form")."<rest of html>";
}
```

Those csrf tokens are supposed to be different (i've checked there's nothing wrong with newCSRF(). But they aren't...
To prove it is supposed to work if I write them as:

```
echo "<some html form>"; echo newCSRF("register-form"); echo "<rest of html>";
```

It works brilliantly. What's wrong with my first spelling?? I don't like the second one, it seems odd to me.

**EDIT** added newCSRF():

```
function newCSRF($formId)
{
    $c_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; //gets the client IPv4 address

    //generates a unique security token, randString has been added beacuse of dupes when refresh spamming.
    //$csrf = dechex(crc32($c_ip."".$formId."".time()."".randString(16)));
    $csrf = hash("crc32", $c_ip + $formId + time() + randString(16));

    try
    {
        $pdo_options[PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE] = PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION;

        //connecting to the sql server
        $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host='.DB_HOST.';dbname='.DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, $pdo_options);

        $a = $bdd->prepare('INSERT INTO csrf (form_id, client_ip, token, expire) VALUES(:form, :ip, :csrf, :expi)');

        $a->execute(array(
                'form'  => ichar($formId),
                'ip'    => $c_ip,
                'csrf'  => $csrf,
                'expi'  => time() + 1800)); //CSRF token remains valid for 15 min.
        $bdd = null;
        log_write("New CSRF token successfuly created", 0, false);
    }
    catch (PDOException $e)
    {
        log_write("Error occured when creating new CSRF token", 3, false);
        log_write("in File: " . __FILE__ . " on line: " . __LINE__ . " : " . $e->getMessage(), 3, false);
        $bdd = null;
        exit(1);
    }
    return $csrf;
}
```

Comment: What are your `if` statements checking for _truthy_-ness?  In your code the evaluations are empty.  Is that how it is in your actual code?

Comment: please provide code for the newCSRF() function.

Comment: Any time someone says "I've checked and I'm sure that there's no problem with ... ", that's almost always where the problem is.

Comment: nope it's just because I want it to be short, they are checking for the presence of $_SESSION['connected'] and his value == 1
but both forms are displayed on the page at the same time anyway. It's to hide them when a user is connected.

Comment: @nakashu I've updated my question

Comment: @PatrickQ newCSRF does give me two different tokens when called in a separate echo. but returns the save value when concatenated in an echo with other strings.

Comment: `$c_ip + $formId + time() + randString(16)` Are you sure you don't want `$c_ip . $formId . time() . randString(16)`? (which I now see you have commented out. why?)

Comment: @PatrickQ That's just a little testing around, trying to see what worked best. Is there any chances that might change the output?
In both cases the output should be very different since formId doesn't has the same value in both calls.

Comment: @PatrickQ Thanks for helping me out ;)
My old syntax seams so have fixed it... Sadly I don't understand why :(

Comment: "Is there any chances that might change the output?"  Yes.  Because one is mathematical addition and the other is string concatenation.  Your call to `time()` is most likely going to return the same value within each call to `newCSRF()` as each call is likely within a second of each other.  Your `randString()` function is also probably not as random as you think it is. As a result, the addition of all those values is giving the same result on each call (the fact that the `$formId` values are different is irrelevant in this case). However, with concatenation, the `$formId` actually makes a diff

Comment: @PatrickQ oh I see... I don't remember why I changed from . to +
I'll change randString to an openssl function ;)

Comment: Your `randString()` function might be fine.  See my answer below.  It is the fact that it's returning a string and not a number that is making it essentially useless given your use of `+` instead of `.`

Comment: @PatrickQ Yeah, I had forgotten that + will just ignore string and not evaluate the "sum".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple factors at play here in terms of why you are getting the same value.  First, both of your calls to `newCSRF()` are likely close enough together that when you call `time()` within each of them, you are getting the same value.  Second, although you don't show the contents of it here, my guess is that `randString()` returns (as its name implies) a text string.  Since you are doing mathematical addition instead of concatenation, the text strings from `$formId` and `randString(16)` really don't help in terms of getting a different value from each call. And since `time()` is the same in both calls, the entire computation is mathematically equivalent in each call.

By switching to concatenation, both `$formId` and `randString(16)` will actually come into play and the fact that `time()` is the same won't be an issue. You'll get a different result from each call to `newCSRF()` (given that `$formId` is different).

In short, the solution is to change `$c_ip + $formId + time() + randString(16)` to `$c_ip . $formId . time() . randString(16)`